# Perforce strange 10s delay/lag on some commands [raspberry-pi / cubieboard]

Tags: linux, arm, perforce

i am trying to setup perforce server on cubieboard2 (raspberry-pi clone)

i have downloaded p4d and p4 for Linux ARM (2011.1)

i am running server like this:

```
p4d -d -r root_path -p 12345 -L log
```

statistics of running commands directly on server machine (server ip 192.168.1.1)

```
p4 -p 12345 users               # it returns immediately
p4 -p 127.0.0.1:12345 users     # it returns immediately
p4 -p localhost:12345 users     # it returns immediately
p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345 users   # it returns immediately
p4 -p 12345 info                # it returns immediately
p4 -p 127.0.0.1:12345 info      # it returns immediately
p4 -p localhost:12345 info      # it returns immediately
p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345 info    # returns after ~10 sec
```

i want to connect to this perforce server from my windows pc, since i am in LAN with the server, i am connecting with *p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345 users* command returns immediately, *info* with 10sec lag (using p4 on my windows pc)
i didn't checked other commands, i am unable to connect with p4Admin or p4v, they hang/do nothing, thus my server is unusable

starting server with

```
p4d -d -r root_path -p 192.168.1.1:12345 -L log
```

makes it impossible to run commands with *p4 -p 12345 or localhost:12345 or 127.0.0.1:12345*
but its same story with 192.168.1.1:12345

Note. i am also running ftp on it, and it runs fine, when connecting through 192.168.1.1

Edit. added strace log for p4d
**strace of *'p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345 users'* ran from win7 pc (ip ends with '13', returns immed.)**

```
{sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(61483), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.13")}, [16]) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, 0xbea31744, WNOHANG, NULL)    = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb6e45068) = 2890
close(4)                                = 0
gettimeofday({1380359365, 320807}, NULL) = 0
accept(3, 0xbea31734, [16])             = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 2890
wait4(-1, 0xbea3141c, WNOHANG, NULL)    = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
sigreturn()                             = ? (mask now [HUP INT QUIT])
accept(3,
```

**strace for p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345 info**

```
{sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(61486), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.13")}, [16]) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, 0xbea31744, WNOHANG, NULL)    = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb6e45068) = 2894
close(4)                                = 0
gettimeofday({1380359462, 822219}, NULL) = 0
accept(3,
```

now it lags, and after, following lines appear

```
          0xbea31734, [16])             = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 2894
wait4(-1, 0xbea3141c, WNOHANG, NULL)    = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {0x16d160, [CHLD], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
sigreturn()                             = ? (mask now [HUP INT QUIT])
accept(3,
```

its not telling me much, but as you can see, the exact same line
accept(3, 0xbea31734, [16])             = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
appears in both logs, and on the latter it stops for 10 sec after 'accept(3, '

As for swap, i had it enabled as swap file on external drive connected to the board, while i am booting from sd-card, either way, no change after disabling it.

Comment: I'm guessing that your hardware is inadequate for running Perforce, which has some significant resource requirements, especially on memory.  I couldn't find any explicit requirements in the Perforce docs, so left this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @gareth_bowles i have more than 900mb RAM free, and running simple info command on clean server does not make 2-core cpu usage above 1%, even if it lags 10s, and how would you explain that info returns immediately when run with p4 -p 12345 vs p4 -p 192.168.1.1:12345, the latter lags

Comment: Umm, cubieboard2 really isn't a raspberry-pi clone. Its dual Cortex-A7 processors are approximately 5 years ahead (including 1 major and several minor architecture revisions) of the single 1176 in the ras-pi.
That said - can you attach an strace (-p <process id>) on the server daemon and see whether it is blocking on some system call? Run top and see what the CPU load is like? Do you have any swap configured? If you do, try disabling it (with 900MB RAM free, shouldn't need it).

Comment: @unixsmurf thank you, but strace log does not tell me much, being new to linux etc., i have added it to my question if you want to check it

Comment: @sv3: doesn't obviously tell me what is causing the problem. It is possible this question would be a better fit for the serverfault site.
Or, this being a commercial product, it might be worth getting in touch with Perforce themselves. Or, just try the latest version - ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r13.3/bin.linux26armel/.
What Linux distribution are you running on your cubieboard2?

Comment: @unixsmurf i am running debian wheezy(kernel 3.4.43+), i have tried p4d from the link you posted, but i am unable to run it: segmentation fault, also tried different versions: 13.2, 13.1, 12.2, all seg. fault. i have downloaded my p4d directly on perforce.com - all version was working, but same problem with 10s delay, i will look around if i can pass this question to perforce gusy

Comment: @sv13: I'm thinking there is a substantial possibility that you have an ABI compatibility issue ... The perforce binaries are all armel, whereas (for performance reasons) a cubieboard2 should be running an armhf distribution (wheezy exists as both). I spotted a blog post about running perforce on raspberry-pi, and if you have been following that one, it recklessly creates a symlink to make the system pick up the armhf linker when the binary asks for the armel one.

Comment: And if that is the case, you could either experiment with armel/armhf multiarch (https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) or debootstrapping an armel wheezy into a subdirectory and chroot into it.

Comment: @unixsmurf you got me, i have created that symlink, i will read a little about the things you posted and will get back with results

Comment: well, following multiarch howto i wasn't able to achieve anything, and for the second option, after whole day of fighting perforce, its beyond my expertise and will to do it :), guess i will try to setup git tomorrow, thanks for your help unixsmurf

Comment: forgot to add, i even tried finding this ld-linux.so.3, that i've created symlink to, found arm-linux-gnueabi with it in libc6 armel package, copied whole folder it to /lib and symlinked, p4 and p4d launched but delay is still there, i guess thats not how its supposed to be done :D

Comment: @unixsmurf you could post an answer about that architecture incompatibility, thats probably the cause anyway, i will accept it